# In JS - why does 77.6*100 not equal 7760

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, casting, floating-point

Came across this, trying to understand why

Initially I thought this was due to type conversations between strings, ints and floats etc, but it appears not.

In JS doing 77.6 * 100, the outcome is 7759.999999999999.

If you do 77.6 * 1000 then the outcome is not 77599.999999999999, but instead is actually 77600.

(77.6*100) == (77.6*1000)/10 will give you false, but

(66.7*100) == (66.7*1000)/10 will give you true

This appears to only happen when 77.6 and 100 are involved, the same happens when you divide also.

I've tried this across Windows and Linux OS's, chrome js console, nodejs as well as PHP. All exhibit the same behaviour.

It's not exactly an insurmountable problem, but I am curious.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Because floats are not precise, and comparing them with `==` is pretty much always a bad idea.

Comment: and it is not only javascript, every languague has this problem. you have to round your float and convert it to int before comparing

Comment: @mtizziani - Not *every* language. Some languages correctly represent base 10 decimal values.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok, not every language, but nearly to every

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't sure if this was just float precision (lack of), or something else.